# pgadmin won't connect to Postgresql via ssh on macOS

Tags: ssh, postgresql, ssh-tunnel, terminal, connection-refused

I am trying, with no success, to connect pgAdmin 4 to my Postgresql installation on Linode using ssh tunnel as specified in https://linode.com/docs/databases/postgresql/securely-manage-remote-postgresql-servers-with-pgadmin-on-macos-x/

It did not work, with pgAdmin giving me:

```
Unable to connect to server:

could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (::1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
could not connect to server: Connection refused
Is the server running on host "localhost" (127.0.0.1) and accepting
TCP/IP connections on port 5432?
```

I spent hours searching for a solution and nothing seems to work. I am for sure missing something. Here is what else I tried:

- I went through all the steps in https://blog.bigbinary.com/2016/01/23/configure-postgresql-to-allow-remote-connection.html
- my `netstat -nlt` shows:

  ```
  tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:3306 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
  tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:587 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
  tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:22 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
  tcp 0 0 0.0.0.0:5432 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
  tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:5433 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
  tcp 0 0 127.0.0.1:25 0.0.0.0:* LISTEN
  tcp6 0 0 :::80 :::* LISTEN
  tcp6 0 0 :::22 :::* LISTEN
  tcp6 0 0 :::5432 :::* LISTEN
  tcp6 0 0 ::1:5433 :::* LISTEN
  ```
- my `ufw status` shows:

  ```
  Status: active
  To Action From
  22 ALLOW Anywhere
  5432/tcp ALLOW Anywhere
  22 (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
  5432/tcp (v6) ALLOW Anywhere (v6)
  ```
- I certainly restarted Postgresql more often than not (for every single modification try)
- if I run `psql -h localhost -p 5433 -U postgres` it works fine
- also with `psql -h localhost -p 5432 -U postgres` all works fine

But nothing else I do works for pgAdmin.

Does anyone can shed a light on it? What am I missing? What else could I try?

Thank you
Greetings from Beijing!
Daniel

Comment: If exactly at the same time, with an ssh instance redirecting localhost port 5432 to some outside server, `psql -h localhost -p 5432` works but `pgAdmin` configured the same way does not, you then have a strange problem... You should really make sure pgAdmin uses this configuration. For low level diagnostics you could use `strace` and `tcpdump` to discover what it does exactly. Make sure to use same username/password in both cases. Also look at your remote postgresql instance log files.

Comment: Also, unrelated, but if you want to avoid `ssh`, PostgreSQL can be reached remotely over TLS and you can restrict the source IPs both at the OS firewall level (iptables) and in PostgreSQL `pg_hba.conf` settings.

Comment: Thanks, Patrick, I finally solved, and it was a stupid mistake. I posted my answer below. It was indeed a "strange" error and I was sure it was something quite simple that I was missing.

Answer (score 1):

It was indeed a stupid error, certainly because I a total newbie on this:

As per [instructions](https://linode.com/docs/databases/postgresql/securely-manage-remote-postgresql-servers-with-pgadmin-on-macos-x/), I entered the command

`ssh -f -L 5433:127.0.0.1:5432 username@remote-host -N`

while already logged into my Linode server. This should have been done on my local machine, **before** logging in Linode.

Otherwise my Mac would have no way of knowing about the tunnel! So obvious, not that I look at it.